# convert pine script version 4 code to a version below 4?

Tags: version, pine-script

I found a pivot points high low example from tradingview documentation, but it's not running with my other codes because my other codes are written in version 3 or 2. And changing my other codes is a bit of work because it's long.

So my option is to figure out how to do the pivot points in version 4 in versions other than 4.

```
//@version=4
study("Pivot Points High Low", shorttitle="Pivots HL", overlay=true)


lenH = input(title="Length High", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)


//if i run the code in version 3, this len below causes problems

fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false

    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false

    if isFound
        label.new(bar_index[len], p, tostring(p), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color)

// good news. i can change the color to white and it will at least look decent even though it loses the arrow point

fun(high, lenH, true, label.style_labeldown, yloc.abovebar, color.lime)
fun(low, lenL, false, label.style_labelup, yloc.belowbar, color.red)
```

Any tips are appreciated

Comment: Here is a tip: Update your other scripts to v4.

Comment: Ok. is there a website that can help me do that? some examples? it seems like the security, color, and some other things are major culprits in breaking the older codes in version 4. how do we know what's causing the problem when the code breaks? the pinescript error messages are not that easy to understand.

Comment: You can always ask your questions here. There shouldn't be any big issues. When you have a compile error, just check the new documentation of that function.

Comment: For v3 scripts, using the converter that is now available is also an option. When you have a v3 script open in the Editor, you will see a new *Convert to v4* button to the right of the "Save" button.

Comment: this worked like a charm. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//@version=3
study("Pivot Points High Low", shorttitle="Pivots HL v3", overlay=true)

lenH = input(title="Length High", defval=10, minval=1)
lenL = input(title="Length Low", defval=10, minval=1)

fun(src, len, isHigh) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false

    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false

    return = isFound ? p : na

pivotHi = fun(high, lenH, true)
pivotLo = fun(low, lenL, false)

plotchar(pivotHi, "PivotHi", "—", location.absolute, lime, 0, offset = -lenH, size = size.large)
plotchar(pivotLo, "PivotLo", "—", location.absolute, red, 0, offset = -lenL, size = size.large)
```

Comment: That's not printing the prices above the candles, which is the best part of the indicator. my guess is that being able to put dynamic numbers like changing prices, or other indicator numbers, on chart as label or as a part of a label is something that is only possible in version 4? is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Only way to print series text in v3 is with a kludge of [this sort](https://www.tradingview.com/script/imUyKfsJ-Print-Trade-Number-PineCoders-FAQ/).